# Haskell runtime in VSCode too long

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell

I recently started learning Haskell by installing it through the official platform and am working on it through the VSCode platform. I have installed the Haskell as well as the code runner extension. But the commands take too long to run.
For printing "hello world" it took me around 7 seconds to get an output. For commands taking user input, it is running for even longer and has not given me an output yet. This is the code I used:

```
main=do
    
    putStrLn "Please enter your name:"
    name <-getLine
    putStrLn name
    putStrLn ("Your name is"++name)
```

I have checked if cabal, stack, GHCup, etc. were installed, they were. I'm not sure if it's an issue with VSCode or Haskell.I also observed when I run the same files on powershell using `ghc -o hello hello.hs`
it gives the error:
`<no location info>: error: Can't find hello.hs`
even though it's in a folder on the desktop.

I have the latest version of VScode and Haskell on a windows 11, ASUS Vivobook. How do I resolve this?

edit: I ran the console inside the folder and it showed this:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Haskell> ghc -o hey hey.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( hey.hs, hey.o )
[2 of 2] Linking hey.exe
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Haskell>
```

It's not showing the error, but there's no output and I get the intermediate files in the same folder, hey.o, hey.hi and hey.exe. This program still gives an output on VSCode though.

This is a new laptop, barely a week old, and I'm wondering if that could be part of the reason?

Comment: When running the program that is asking for user input, did you enter any input?

Comment: Check if you are running any antivirus. See what happens if you disable it

Comment: It doesn't give the prompt for entering the user input at that stage

Comment: Disabling my antivirus temporarily reduces the runtime from 7.3 to 4.9 seconds for printing "hello world", but user input code still doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps VSCode is to blame.

Comment: "even though it's in a folder on the desktop" Programs normally will not search through all the folders on the desktop. Are you familiar with the notion of "current working directory"?

Comment: Yes, my current working directory is `C:\Users\User` . My program is located in `c:\Users\User\Desktop\Haskell\hello.hs`. Is it possible it is not being searched by the program?

Comment: @metanetfuture. You should open a console in `c:\Users\User\Desktop\Haskell\hello.hs`. Why do you expect `ghc` to search in your desktop?

Comment: It is not only possible, it is 1000% certain.

Comment: I ran the console in the folder, it gives me the intermediate files but no output

Comment: @metanetfuture you compiled the program, you didn't run it. When compiling a program you produce an executable (<name>.exe on windows) which you can run. Double click on the executable to run it, or in the console type `./hey.exe`. Notice that windows is overprotective when it comes to execute untrust executables, so you may need admin permission. Also, I'd recommend you to read a little bit more about what is a compiled language vs interpreted language, because It seems like you treat Haskell like an interpreted lang, some sort of python/javascript way